# Flatten numpy array and keep index values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Supposing I have the following matrix, either `pandas` or `numpy`:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

I am looking for a way to reshape this array to 1D and keep the index of that cell as a column name so that if the above was to be flattened, the outcome would be as such:

```
>>> array([['i1j1', 'i1j2', 'i1j3', 'i2j1', 'i2j2', 'i2j3', 'i3j1', 'i3j2','i3j3'],
          ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], dtype='<U4')
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A, 
                  columns=[f'j{j+1}' for j in range(A.shape[1])], 
                  index=[f'i{i+1}' for i in range(A.shape[0])]).stack()
df.index = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.index]
df_out = df.to_frame().T
df_out
```

Output:

```
   i1j1  i1j2  i1j3  i2j1  i2j2  i2j3  i3j1  i3j2  i3j3
0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
b = (pd.DataFrame(A)
     .rename(lambda x: 'i{}'.format(x+1))
     .rename(lambda x: 'j{}'.format(x+1),axis=1)
     .stack())
b = b.set_axis(b.index.map(''.join)).to_frame().T
```

Comment: I like your use of set_axis with map join to flatten multiindex as a chained method to a dataframe. +1

Answer (score 0):

as you noticed, there is a very intuitive way to calculate the indices of the flattened array. We can use `np.meshgrid` to take advantage of that.

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(A.shape[0]), np.arange(A.shape[1])) 
indices = np.stack(( yv.flatten(), xv.flatten()), axis=1)
```

outputs

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Edit:

To get the exact format you have in your example, try:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(A.shape[0]) + 1, np.arange(A.shape[1]) + 1)  
rows = np.char.add('i', yv.flatten().astype(str)) 
cols = np.char.add('j', xv.flatten().astype(str))
indicies = np.char.add(rows,cols)
np.stack((indicies, A.flatten()))
```

returns

```
array([['i1j1', 'i1j2', 'i1j3', 'i2j1', 'i2j2', 'i2j3', 'i3j1', 'i3j2', 'i3j3'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], dtype='<U24')
```